# How to fake screen resolution

Tags: android

Is there a way to make Android believe the current device has a certain screen size (pixels, not density) which is smaller than the actual display size (again pixels, not density)?

I need the following: On a device (not emulator) with a 1280x720 pixel (for example) display I want to use only 800x480 pixels - resulting in a homescreen attached to one of the corners and the rest of the display left black (or whatever color).

This has nothing to do with screen resolution since changing the resolution would fill the complete screen - which is what I don't want (see above).

Similar questions on SO have not been answered with any help.

Answer (score 1):

`DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();`
`getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);`

`metrics.heightPixels;`
`metrics.widthPixels;`

Comment: Thanks. This is how to GET the heigth and width. I need to SET it. Small difference in the word, but huge in the meaning. :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can  fix height and width of your main layout

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_height="800px"
    android:layout_width="480px">
    ...
    ...

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks - but this is not a sufficient solution. Within an app the status bar (clock, symbols for wifi...) and app title bar will stay full length and outside the app the homescreen will not be affected at all. What I need is a more deeper change within the system - maybe requiring root access.